# Query & Transpose Data Every Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have database in google sheet, Let's say the named sheet is Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. In sheet 1 has four columns as below:

[image]

Then in sheet 2, i have two columns in below:

ID Primary Time

My goal is I want to query data and transpose value from sheet 1 to sheet 2, as example below:

[image]

Before that, I have created formula query & transpose in Sheet 2, but it not worked. Here's my formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", QUERY({Sheet1!A:D},"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL", 0)), ","))
```

Does anyone know how the formula to solve this problem? Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!A2:D,{1,3,2,4}),3),2)
```